# MonetDB delete table fully

Tags: python, monetdb, squirrel-sql

I had created some tables in sys. how to delete them fully? 
can i do that :
1.drop table [your_tablename]
2.delete table [your_tablename]
but my teacher told me that is wrong,how should I write a SQL statement?

and my MonetDB's version is [MonetDB Database Server Toolkit v1.1 (Jul2015-SP2)]

i used squirrel to connect.like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxsXn.png)

Comment: What's wrong with `drop table <table_name>`?

Comment: if i drop a lots of tables(maybe there tablename is the same) ,how to know the table where i drop is in sys? can i do like this :set schema sys;drop table <table_name>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [`MonetDB`](https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation) documentation, it should be

```
drop table <table_name>
```

Read more about the [`Drop Statement`](https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/Manuals/SQLreference/DropStatement).

Comment: sorry bro,is my fault.my english is so bad that i can't explain my problem clearly.the tables which i created was in Multiple servers（192.168.1.100..200）and there are three port per ip(means every server has three db).something wrong when i only used sqlcmd like:drop table <table_name>.finally in my classmate's help,i solve it.

Comment: sqlcmd:set schema sys;drop table <table_name>;delete from _tables where schema_id in(select id from schemas where name = 'sys') and name =<table_name>

Comment: tks,for your answer.